# How do i get a JS code inside an object and apply already formatted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am acessing an API and i need to put a content with a full JS code already formatted in my react app, anyone knows how?

This is part of the code i wanna extract:

```
<p>Site de pequenas empresas podem ser desenvolvidos com os mesmos preceitos de sites de grandes negócios.</p> <p>Os recursos tecnológicos estão cada vez mais acessíveis.</p> <p>Plataformas de conteúdo como o WordPress, líder mundial, utilizado por empresas de todos os tamanhos, estão disponíveis gratuitamente. Segue a tabela com a parcela de mercado que o WP ocupa e tire suas próprias conclusões:</p> <figure id="attachment_9120" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-9120" style="width: 750px" class="wp-caption aligncenter"><img loading="lazy" width="750" height="121" class="size-full wp-image-9120" src="https://blog.apiki.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/06/site-pequenas-empresas-wordpress-stats.png" alt="Estatísticas do WordPress" srcset="https://blog.apiki.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/06/site-pequenas-empresas-wordpress-stats.png 750w, https://blog.apiki.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/06/site-pequenas-empresas-wordpress-stats-300x48.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 750px) 100vw, 750px" />
```

I need to do this dynamically, because its a lot of parts like that.

Thank you everyone <3

Comment: Maybe [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) helps but not 100% sure if I understood correctly your question.

Comment: OMG its exactly that what i was looking for :D
Ty